# Need for loop to repeat if a yes is answered. For and Do while loop

Tags: java

For my program i am required to calculate the factorial of a number inputed by the user and then ask the them if they want to enter another number. If yes then the loop should repeat itself and calculate the input of the new number. For the program I am required to use a for loop and a do while loop. I have the calculating a factorial part down. However I am very confused as to how I am to get the loop to repeat itself after the word yes is entered. Your help is greatly appreciated.
Yes I know that there is no do while loop in the program at the moment, that is why I need help. I don't know how to go about the entire situation. As of now my question has not been solved. Also stating that iv'e "not done my research" is not true and does not help the situation either. All help is appreciated

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog162a
{ //begin testshell 
public static void main (String[] args)
{ //begin main
    Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);

    //input 
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    long number= kbReader.nextLong();
    long factorial= 1
    for ( int multiply=2;multiply<number;multiply++);
         { //begin value lopp
            factorial = factorial * multiply
            } // end value loop
       //output
       System.out.print("The calue of " +number+"! is " +multiply);
       System.out.println("\nWould you like to calculate another number?");

    }//end main
}//end testshell
```

Here is a sample output.

Enter a Number: 6
The value of 6! is 720

Would you like to calculate another number?   Yes

Enter a Number: 9
The value of 9! is 362880

Would you like to calculate another number?   Yes

Enter a Number : 12
The value of 12! is 479001600

Would you like to calculate another number?   No

"End Factorial Processing"

Comment: Have you tried any loop ? If so, where and what was the problem ?

Comment: I don't see any attempt at a do/while loop. Have you done any research about this?

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I don't know where to start. That is the problem. I have thought about it and it just does not make sense to me

Comment: Yes i have researched. I do not understand

Comment: What you want is a loop like any other.  What code do you want to be repeated in the loop?  What condition would exit the loop?

Comment: Start by reading about java loop structures or controls. Google is your friend here.

Comment: What don't you understand? A cursory search for `java do while input` reveals numerous questions and resources regarding looping until some specific input is given.

Comment: I do not understand how to make the entire for loop repeat itself after the word yes is entered at the end of the program at the output section. Also i do not understand how to implement the do while loop.

Comment: If that's the case then you definitely haven't done any research. Again, A cursory search for `java do while input` will give you what you need. [Here's an in depth tutorial](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c3/s3.html).

Comment: what i am not understanding is I need the for loop to run once by itself. then AFTER the loop is ran alone the question is is asked if the user wants another. when they enter yes I need the loop to run again. I do not know how to do this unless I ask the question first which is what the output is supposed to do.

Comment: You're describing a do/while loop. You've clearly not read the link I included earlier. It covers this specifically: "To execute a do loop, the computer **first executes the body of the loop** -- that is, the statement or statements inside the loop -- and **then it evaluates the boolean expression**."

Comment: perhaps first try implementing it so that it will ask once, and repeat once if they say 'yes', then try to compare that to a situation that will ask and repeat indefinitely until they say 'no'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic structure of what you're looking to accomplish using a do-while loop.

```
String answer; //this will store the answer
do{ //starts loop
    //everything you're trying to do during the loop goes here
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue?"); //asks them if they want to continue
    answer = input.nextLine() //input will reference your scanner variable and puts answer into the variable we made
}while(answer.equals("yes"); //ends the loop when answer is equal to yes
```

Hopefully the comments will help you understand what is going on.

You'll most likely also want to make sure they answer either yes or no, and convert their answer to lower or upper case so when you check what it equals it's not case-sensitive.

Comment: Ok so i did this and now the loop wont repeat. It just asks the question and doesnt let the user input yes or no and just finishes the loop.

Comment: do{
               for ( long multiply2 = 2 ;multiply2 < number;multiply2++)
               { //begin factorial lopp
                   factorial2 *= multiply2;
                } // end factorial loop
                System.out.print("The calue of " +number+"! is " +factorial2);
                System.out.println("\nWould you like to calculate another number?");
                answer = kbReader.nextLine(); // stores the new yes or no into the answer variable
          
            }while(answer.equals("yes"));

Comment: This is what my output looks like Enter a number: 9
The calue of 9! is 40320
Would you like to calculate another number?
End Factorial Processing

Comment: This is because when you use nextInt or nextLong in your case, it doesn't capture the full line, therefore it never moves to the next line. This is a problem because when you do nextLine it'll just take that blank space. The easiest way to fix it is before your input just have a blank yourScanner.nextLine()

Answer (score 0):

Here I do added an if statement towards the bottom of the loop to allow for it to exit if the user enter 'no'

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog162a
{ //begin testshell 
public static void main (String[] args)
{ //begin main
    Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);

    //input 
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    long number= kbReader.nextLong();
    long factorial= 1
    for ( int multiply=2; multiply<number; multiply++);
         { //begin value loop
            factorial = factorial * multiply
            } // end value loop
       //output
       System.out.print("The value of " +number+"! is " +multiply);
       System.out.println("\nWould you like to calculate another number? Please enter yes or no");
       if(kbReader.nextLine().toLowerCase() == "no"){ //if user enters 'no' then it exits program  
        break; //this exits the loop (you could also use 'return;')
       }

    }//end main
}//end testshell
```

Comment: Where's the do-while?

Comment: You don't need a do while but you could certainly use a regular while loop. Inserting an if statement is the easiest for his current solution

Comment: From the OPs question: "For the program I am required to use a for loop and a do while loop"

Comment: Ah - I didn't see that. Let me see if I can fix it

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reuse some of your code. Basically I moved your code to a second function (calculation function) and added some missing semicolons. This new function gets called in an endless `while(true)` loop. After each call inside the loop the user is asked for typeing *yes*. If the user doesn't type *yes* the loop will break itself and quit your programm.

```
private static Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // endless loop (because I put true inside the brackets and not a variable check)
    while(true) {
        calculate(); // call your calculation code
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to calculate another number? (type 'yes'): ");
        // reads the command line input
        String input = kbReader.next();
        // the exclamation mark is a short form for saying that the result is false
        if (!input.equals("yes")) break; // leaving the loop
    }

}

private static void calculate() {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    long number = kbReader.nextLong();
    long factorial = 1;
    for (int multiply = 2; multiply < number + 1; multiply++){
        factorial = factorial * multiply;
    }
    System.out.print("The value of " + number + "! is " + factorial);
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Pay attention on `multiplay < number + 1` inside the for-loop. Without saying `number + 1` the result of 6 would be 120 (not 720).